# Regular Expression Python, marking beginning and end of string?

Tags: python, regex, string

So I just started getting into regex today for python and I can't seem to get this to work.

So I have the string

```
"2800 Software (C2800NM-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.4(24)T8, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)"
```

It's some output from a cisco router and I need to pull the version number. The version number is the string after "Version" and it ends with the ",". Can I write a regex that would pull the Version number every time based on "Version" occuring before and "," right after? I just need "12.4(24)T8" pulled and other routers have different numbers that are completely different.

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to extract the version from this single string, you can use [`re.search()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.search) to do this.

```
>>> import re
>>> s = '2800 Software (C2800NM-ADVIPSERVICESK9-M), Version 12.4(24)T8, RELEASE SOFTWARE (fc1)'
>>> re.search(r'\bVersion\s*([^,]+)', s).group(1)
'12.4(24)T8'
```

If you have multiple strings that you need to extract from, use [`re.findall()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall)

```
>>> re.findall(r'\bVersion\s*([^,]+)', s)
['12.4(24)T8']
```

Explanation:

```
\b         # the boundary between a word character (\w) and not a word character
Version    # 'Version'
\s*        # whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times)
(          # group and capture to \1:
  [^,]+    #   any character except: ',' (1 or more times)
)          # end of \1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Version\s*(\S+?),
```

Try this.Use match.group(1) to get your result.

Or you can use this.

```
print re.findall(r"Version\s*(\S+?),",x)
```

Or you can use this.

```
print re.search(r"Version\s*(\S+?),",x).group(1)
```

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/bA0jG5/10